# How to set the cursor focus on input field?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I would like to set the cursor focus on an input field as soon as the form (directive) is shown. I tried adding the following code to my link function:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element('input[name=headline]').focus();
}
```

But it does not work. I also tried the following variants:

```
element.find('input[name=headline]').focus();
element.querySelector('input[name=headline]').focus();
```

I did not find any useful information on the Web. `md-autofocus` seems to have nothing to do with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you give us a fiddle or plkr of your problem?

Comment: Would not `autofocus` html attribute help in your case? http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_autofocus.asp

Comment: Or in case of angular: ng-focus (to true) on your input

Answer (score 5):

### Option 1

HTML [autofocus](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

### Option 2

Try playing with [ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) from angular.

### Update

My bad, `ng-focus`, from the doc:

> Specify custom behavior on focus event.

So ng-focus is not what you need to use. keep on `autofocus`.

### Final solution with ng-if

https://plnkr.co/edit/sb29aGHGtdFQ7fiLdbtN?p=preview

Create a directive that will apply the focus for you.

```
myApp.directive('yourAutofocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function($scope, $element) {
      $element[0].focus();
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime, I found the HTML autofocus attribute also. It works for the first time, but when the directive is recreated (ng-if), it no longer works. As for ng-focus, it seems to call a function when the input field gets focus... right?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
ng-if="showMe" ng-focus="true && showMe" or ng-focus="focudMe=true; showMe=true"
```